# How to GROUP BY a column that is a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the below query (Oracle SQL) which uses a sub-query in one of the columns.

I will like to GROUP BY the column that is a sub-query. Can someone advise what is the approach?

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT B.TYPE FROM INTERNAL_DATA B WHERE A.COUNTRY = B.COUNTRY AND B.DEAL = A.DEAL) "TYPE", 
  A.CHARGE_NO, 
  A.DISCOUNT ,
  COUNT(1)
FROM CHARGE_TABLE A 
WHERE A.COUNTRY = 'US' AND 
A.STEP_TYPE IN ('ISSUANCE','AMENDMENT') AND 
A.DEAL LIKE '_____02%' 
AND A.CHARGE_NO LIKE '8%' 
GROUP BY TYPE, A.CHARGE_NO, A.DISCOUNT;
```

Comment: You are not using any aggregate functions. Why are you using `GROUP BY` in the first place?

Comment: Apologies, left out the COUNT.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just as easy to use a JOIN in the query above? I'm not sure what is gained by using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need make one more subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 
      (SELECT B.TYPE FROM INTERNAL_DATA B WHERE A.COUNTRY = B.COUNTRY AND B.DEAL = A.DEAL) "TYPE", 
      A.CHARGE_NO, 
      A.DISCOUNT 
    FROM CHARGE_TABLE A 
    WHERE A.COUNTRY = 'US' AND 
    A.STEP_TYPE IN ('ISSUANCE','AMENDMENT') AND 
    A.DEAL LIKE '_____02%' 
    AND A.CHARGE_NO LIKE '8%' )
GROUP BY TYPE, CHARGE_NO, DISCOUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `WITH` clause:

```
WITH INT_DATA AS
  (SELECT B.TYPE
  FROM INTERNAL_DATA B,
    CHARGE_TABLE A1
  WHERE A1.COUNTRY = B.COUNTRY
  AND B.DEAL      = A1.DEAL
  )
SELECT I.TYPE AS "TYPE",
  A.CHARGE_NO,
  A.DISCOUNT ,
  COUNT(1)
FROM CHARGE_TABLE A,
  INT_DATA I
WHERE A.COUNTRY  = 'US'
AND A.STEP_TYPE IN ('ISSUANCE','AMENDMENT')
AND A.DEAL LIKE '_____02%'
AND A.CHARGE_NO LIKE '8%'
GROUP BY I.TYPE,
  A.CHARGE_NO,
  A.DISCOUNT 
;
```